# Firebase Invite for Beta App (Google Play Store Beta and iOS Testlfight)

Tags: firebase, google-play, testflight, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

Does Firebase Invitie Dynamic Links / Referal Links work for Google Play Store Beta Apps and/or for iOS Testflight Apps?

Our game app is currently in Beta and we're about to add a referal system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Invites is powered by the same backend as Firebase Dynamic Links, but there are differences. Most relevant here: Firebase Invites do not supports most link behavior parameters that Firebase Dynamic Links do.

Below information about Firebase Dynamic Links.

Firebase Dynamic Links on iOS will function when App is in TestFlight. Keep in mind:

1) User who tap on the link must have access to your iOS Beta App in TestFlight. I believe, to make this happens you need to invite user to TestFlight first.

2) You can specify "ifl"/"afl" parameter during dynamic link creation. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually . If this parameter is specified, the user will be navigated to your custom link, not AppleStore/PlayStore.

Answer (score 0):

One of the parameters when creating a Firebase Dynamic link is a Fallback Url.  Reference [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create) and [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create):

[image]

If you are using Test Flight, you can now send a [public link](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09262018a) to users to invite them to install your app.

In App Store Connect, open your app > click on the TestFlight menu at the top > select your test group to the left > Click "Enable Public Link".

[image]

Copy your link and add it to the fallback url parameter of the iOS parameters builder when generating your Firebase Dynamic Link.